# Eclipse Auto Save before build?

Tags: eclipse, macos, ide, autosave

Coming from a Visual Studio background...

How do I tell Eclipse that it should auto save when ever I build rather than ask each time.

VS.NET has it under "Options", but I can't find it in Eclipse.

I use a Mac.

Comment: None of the answers seem to work anymore (Eclipse 2019-09). Note that "save before launching" is not the same as "save before build"

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Go to

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace

and there you can check:

`Save automatically before build` + `Build automatically`

Comment: ur answer saved me downloading some plugin

Comment: this is not what OP is asking for, see answer below @um.anusorn

Comment: @Scott Stensland These answers are now the same for "build". "Prompt" is now the installed default under run/debug->launch. Cross developers would never think to look there as they may not ever run/debug.

Answer (score 82):

First, try

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace. There you can check
>   "Save automatically before build" and "Build automatically."

If that does not work,

**PLEASE TRY**

> **Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> "Save dirty editors before**
>   **launching"**

Comment: sad but true - both these need to be checked before eclipse juno will save dirty edits prior to either build or build/run

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me in Kepler, since the Workspace config didn't have any effect.. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

#### Save automatically before build

**Window** > **Preferences** > **General** > **Workspace** > check **"Save automatically before build"** > **OK**

[image: Window Preferences]
[image: General Workspace]

#### Save dirty editors before launching

**Window** > **Preferences** > **Run/Debug** > **Launching** > check **"Always"** for **"Save required dirty editors before launching"**

[image: Launching]

#### Save resources before launching

This is actually an alternative to *"Save required dirty editors before launching"*

Change something in the current file > **Run** > check **"Always save resources before launching"** > **OK**

[image] 
[image]

**Details**:

- IDE: **Eclipse Kepler**
- O.S.: Windows

Answer (score 4):

Preferences -> run/debug ->launching -> Save required dirty editors before launching.

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in Eclipse Luna (or maybe it's just because I'm on a mac and the answerers are on a PC).

You find it under this menu:

**Eclipse** -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace

From there, you check "Save automatically before build" + "Build automatically".  On a Mac, Preferences isn't under the Window menu, so that confused me for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

(Just for completeness)

After
**Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace**

(x) **Save automatically before build + Build automatically**

You must go to:

**Windows -> Save Perspective As...**

And select a name according to the perspective you are using. You can overwrite the old ones...